# Django get sub domain from which the request was sent from

Tags: django

i have a standalone front ends serving on different sub domains, and a single backend responding to all requests through API(s)

Say i have following subdomains

```
first.example.com
second.example.com
third.example.com
```

and my backend is at

```
backend.example.com
```

in my backend views i want to know which subdomain sent me request

i tried

```
self.request.get_host().split('.')[0]
```

but this gave me "backend" as result from every sub-domain

what i want to have :

- if request was sent from first.example.com > in my
  backend.example.com view i want to have "first"
- if request was sent from second.example.com > in my
  backend.example.com view i want to have "second"

and so on

Technologies information:

- Subdomains using **React**
- Backend using **Django**
- Server **Nginx**
- other server **Gunicorn**

Answer (score 1):

You can get subdomain name from HTTP_REFERER

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

urlparse(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')).hostname.split('.')[0]
```